# Why does a generated-with-PDF-Box PDF form with multi-line text boxes results look different on a cloud server?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a web app that fills a PDF form using PDF Box.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am having problems with space characters in multi-line text fields.

[image]

The empty form is available at:

https://www.taxdataexchange.org/pdf-template

The filled form can be seen at:

https://www.taxdataexchange.org/pdf-template-filled

Here is my code:

```
package processors;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;

import utils.BytesToFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class TemplateFiller {

    public static final String LF = "\n";

    public TemplateFiller( ) {

    }

    public ByteArrayOutputStream fill( ) throws IOException {

        ClassLoader classLoader = TemplateFiller.class.getClassLoader( );
        String templateFilePath = "pdf/form.template.pdf";
        InputStream templateStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( templateFilePath );

        String singleLine = "Single line";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( );
        for ( int i = 1; i < 16; i++ ) {
            stringBuilder.append( String.format( "This is line number %d.", i ) ).append( LF );
        }
        String multiLine = stringBuilder.toString( );

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

        try (
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load( templateStream )
        ) {

            PDDocumentCatalog pdDocCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog( );

            PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocCatalog.getAcroForm( );

            // ===============================================
            // Fill in the AcroFields
            // ===============================================
            PDField field1 = acroForm.getField( "Title" );
            field1.setValue( singleLine );

            PDField field2 = acroForm.getField( "Contents" );
            field2.setValue( multiLine );

            doc.save( byteArrayOutputStream );

        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream;

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        TemplateFiller templateFiller = new TemplateFiller( );

        BytesToFile.writeToDirFile(
            templateFiller.fill().toByteArray(),
            "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Downloads",
            "filled.pdf"
        );

    }

}


@WebServlet( "/pdf-template-filled" )
public class PdfTemplateFilled extends BaseServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {

        TemplateFiller templateFiller = new TemplateFiller( );
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = templateFiller.fill( );

        byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray( );
        String fileName = "filled-form.pdf";
        downloadPdfFile( request, response, fileName, pdfBytes );

    }

}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include more code and the PDFs and explain what you mean with "results". Is this json there the content of one field?

Comment: Indeed, without anything to analyze there is nothing we can do.

Comment: There's more happening than these 2 lines of code. The field font is "Cour" but later "CoBo". The form is flattened. You don't tell what version you're using.

Comment: I simplified the example pdf and supplied the entire code as of 08/09/2021 12:30pm MDT. The code works fine on my Mac but in the Google App Engine environment it doesn't work. Does PDF box try to do its' own word placement on multi-line fields? Does it need font files to be in the environment somewhere?

Comment: Is there any log output? (Are logs enabled?) The PDF standard 14 fonts should be on the system, especially ("Courier"). Yes PDFBox does its own placement of the text. It seems it gets some glyphs witdths wrong on that system, for whatever reason.